# Adding links to basic HTML/JavaScript mouseover/pop ups

Tags: javascript, html

This is a very odd series of events, as I am limited to only using very basic (pre-2002) HTML and JavaScript code. Essentially I'm building a Sega Dreamcast compatible site, and the Dreamcast browser won't recognise CSS coding or anything as recent as HTML5.

I am attempting to build a menu that appears when you roll your mouse cursor over an image. This part is working perfectly, and isn't giving me a problem. This issue I'm having is assigning href links to this process.
Currently the pop-up menu is a single image, which I've attempted to use  coordinates to link to, but this caused two issues. Firstly the map coordinates are fixed, and don't disappear when the pop up is closed, and secondly it seems the browser doesn't "stack" what your mouse is hovering over. As such when you hover over a link, the browser can't tell you're still hovering over the image and it closes the actual pop up menu - then the menu spasms open and closed erratically.

Is there a way around this? Or is there a way to load in multiple images on the mouse hover to make each individual image a link of its own?

Here's a CodePen with some placeholder images from Google Searches - codepen.io/Roareye/pen/ExgYjJR
Imagine each of the letters/words of the "Kawaii" image were links to different pages. That's what I am trying to do.

Here's a video of the site page as it stands, so you can see what I mean by the menu drop downs.
https://youtu.be/uogWMxZbNwc

Here's the code I'm using;

````
```html
         <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
        
        if (document.images) {
          button1Red = new Image
          button1Blue = new Image
          button2Red = new Image
          button2Blue = new Image
        
          button1Red.src = "images/menu-complete.jpg"
          button1Blue.src = "images/ChatBubbleLeftGood.gif"
          button2Red.src = "images/menu-leaderboards.jpg"
          button2Blue.src = "images/ChatBubbleLeftGood2.gif"
        }
        
        function chgImg(imgField,newImg) {
              if (document.images) {
                document[imgField].src = eval(newImg + ".src")
              }
            }
        
        
        </script>
            
        <img src="images/Sonic-Waiting.gif" title="Official Websites" border="0" >
        <a href="#" onMouseover="chgImg('button1','button1Red')" onMouseout="chgImg('button1','button1Blue')"><img src="images/ChatBubbleLeftGood.gif" border="0" name="button1" alt="button1"></a><br>
        
        
        <img src="../../images/blank.gif" height="104" width="317" border="0">
        <img src="images/Knuckles-Waiting.gif" title="Official Websites" border="0" >
        <a href="#" onMouseover="chgImg('button2','button2Red')" onMouseout="chgImg('button2','button2Blue')"><img src="images/ChatBubbleLeftGood2.gif" border="0" name="button2" alt="button2"></a>
    
    <div class="map-selector">
            <map name="image-map" id="image-map">
                <area alt="" title="" href="sonic1.html" shape="rect" coords="5,29,100,49" />
                <area alt="" title="" href="sonic2.html" shape="rect" coords="5,49,100,69" />
                <area alt="" title="" href="sonicshuffle.html" shape="rect" coords="5,69,100,93" />
            </map>

```
````

Comment: Still thinking on this for you, but right off the bat I'd have to say you'd want to move away from the eval() statement as much as possible. There's got to be a better way. As they say, "eval() is evil." (Great nerd T-Shirt for that, btw.)

Comment: Can you create a Codepen example for this so that we can see what you mean?

Comment: It is not even clear what `eval` is supposed to achieve here. You are doing mere string concatenation there, to create a file name - that does not need eval-uating _as JS code_ at any point.

Comment: I'm following coding sites, that was the code that allowed me to bring up multiple mouseover pop-ups. If eval is not doing anything, then perhaps any suggestions on cleaner code that would still function?

And I'm still stuck on making these pop up menus function. I might be able to assign a single link, but Dreamkey 2.0 seemed to show multiple options on hover pop-ups, and that's the core problem. If eval is worthwhile or not is irrelevant.

@Volomike - I do not know what Codepen is, I'll look it up.

Comment: @Volomike I got a CodePen, but as there's no online stored images, it's kinda hard to make out what is going on. I don't yet have a server to link the images from.

https://codepen.io/Roareye/pen/ExgYjJR

Comment: Updated the CodePen with some images online - https://codepen.io/Roareye/pen/ExgYjJR

Imagine each of the letters/words of the "Kawaii" image were links to different pages. That's what I am trying to do.

Comment: Here's a video of the site page as it stands, so you can see what I mean by the menu drop downs.
https://youtu.be/uogWMxZbNwc

Comment: Is each individual image a character that can move around, and therefore the static image map doesn't work very well? You can take a DIV, set the background to your image, and set the DIV to relative position. Then, create A links inside that DIV with position absolute, and the A links can contain images inside. When the user hovers, you can also move another A link for metadata popup info. Use z-index for image stacking.

Comment: @Volomike
The background layer is set to the Green Hill Zone background as seen in the video link.
Each character is an animated GIF, they are simply in a "waiting" pose and static on the page - they do not move around. Next to each character is a speech bubble image, which is swapped with a JPG of the menu when it is highlighted. When the mouse moves off of the menu JPG, it returns to being a speech bubble again.

Are you able to show me an example of the DIV A and Z links you mentioned?